# How to know when memory is free'd after onTrimMemory callback in Android?

Tags: android, android-memory

I'm listening to onTrimMemory callbacks (such as RUNNING_CRITICAL) to reduce the memory footprint of my application. However, I'm not sure when I can again increase my app's memory footprint.

Is there a callback available when system is back to normal memory state?

TIA